# OCI Container Instances - Container Instance Getting Deleted Right After Creation

Tags: cloud, deployment, hosting, container

I am confused. I wanted to create a container instance in oci. It failed and I don't know why.
I am the owner of everything used, meaning it cannot be missing priviliges.
And the image exists. Why do I know that? Because you can only select images that exist. :)

I found this post: https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Cloud/2952085_1.html.

Overview:
[image: overview (tried 2 times)]
The Problem:
[image: the problem]
The Error:
[image: the error]
No logs.
[image: no logs...]
I found creation errors, but they don't make any sense.
[image: i found creation errors, but they don't make any sense]
Why does the user, that created the compartment (AND IS ROOT USER) not have the permissions to use it, to create container instances or use images?
[image: Why does the user, that created the compartment (AND IS ROOT USER) not have the permissions to use it, to create container instances or use images?]